# Avoid for-loops when need to calculate each subset aside in r

Tags: r, subset

> dput(list[200:250,])

```
structure(list(id = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 14L), group = c(3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 
2, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2)), .Names = c("id", 
"group"), row.names = c(3618L, 3218L, 3372L, 3613L, 3217L, 3531L, 
3653L, 3835L, 3748L, 3740L, 4007L, 3769L, 3915L, 3834L, 3813L, 
3927L, 4066L, 4048L, 3978L, 3731L, 4030L, 3721L, 3869L, 4070L, 
4021L, 3789L, 3749L, 3739L, 3964L, 3924L, 4023L, 4284L, 4238L, 
4102L, 4642L, 4309L, 4577L, 4784L, 4125L, 4346L, 4088L, 4406L, 
4785L, 4893L, 4347L, 4498L, 4758L, 4686L, 4469L, 4864L, 4193L
), class = "data.frame")
```

my  code:

```
for (i in 1:(max(list$id))) {
  p <- subset(list,list$id==i)
  h <-0
  for (j in 1:(nrow(p)-1)){ 
    if (p$group[j]!=p$group[(j+1)]) {
      h <- (h+1)
      } 
    }
  list$group_move[list$id==i] <- h
}
```

error:

```
Error in if (p$group[j] != p$group[(j + 1)]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

- I checked for N/A (is.na(list)) and it was false.

about my list:

I have 5000 id's, I can have "34526" as an id.
I need to calculate for every different id the number of times they moved between groups 1,2 and 3.
I know 2 "for" is not efficient but I don't know a different way to differentiate every id.

if you can help me understand what's the problem with my code It would be great.
if you know of a way to write commends for every different id it would be even better (the commends are not regular functions).

Comment: your example data has no movement between `group`s. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @ MichaelChirico change it in the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr` and calling your data `dd`:

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    summarize(changes = sum(lag(group) != group, na.rm = T))
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
#      id changes
#   <int>   <int>
# 1    10       0
# 2    12       7
# 3    14       8
```

The above summarizes the number of moves for each group. To instead add this column to the original data frame, we replace `summarize` with `mutate`:

```
dd2 = dd %>% 
    group_by(id) %>% 
    mutate(group_move = sum(lag(group) != group, na.rm = T))
dd2
# Source: local data frame [51 x 3]
# Groups: id [3]
# 
#       id group group_move
#    <int> <dbl>      <int>
# 1     10     3          0
# 2     10     3          0
# 3     10     3          0
# 4     10     3          0
# 5     10     3          0
# 6     10     3          0
# 7     12     2          7
# 8     12     2          7
# 9     12     1          7
# 10    12     3          7
# # ... with 41 more rows
```

I think the only problem with your code is that it can hit `id` values that don't exist. This leads to  empty subsets and the missing condition error you got. A simple fix is to replace `for (i in 1:(max(list$id)))` with `for (i in unique(list$id))`:

```
list = dd

for (i in unique(list$id)) {
  p <- subset(list,list$id==i)
  h <-0
  for (j in 1:(nrow(p)-1)){ 
    if (p$group[j] != p$group[(j+1)]) {
      h <- (h+1)
    } 
  }
  list$group_move[list$id==i] <- h
}
```

This works, but will be much slower than the `dplyr` version. We could speed it up by replacing the inner loop with vectorization:

```
for (i in unique(list$id)) {
  p <- subset(list,list$id==i)
  h <- sum(p$group[-1] != p$group[-nrow(p)])
  list$group_move[list$id==i] <- h
}
```

This is essentially what we did with `dplyr` at the top - the `lag()` is a convenience function to offset the indices, and the `group_by()` takes care of the handling of each `id` separately.

Comment: if I want to calculate standard deviation and slope for each id how would I do that? is this is ok? h <- list %>% group_by(id) %>% summarize(new_list = sd(value), na.rm = T)

Comment: Almost, you want the `na.rm = T` to be an argument to `sd()` not to `summarize()`.

Comment: so what do I need to change?

Comment: You have `summarize(new_list = sd(value), na.rm = T)` - see how the `na.rm = T` is *outside* the closing paren of `sd`? Change that to put it *inside* `sd()`. So you should have `summarize(new_list = sd(value, na.rm = T))`. This doesn't matter if you don't have missing values in your data (then you don't need the `na.rm = T` at all),

Comment: `na.rm = T` is only needed in my answer because my `lag(group)` creates a missing value, it turns `1, 2, 3` into `NA, 1, 2`.

Comment: How would you find the slope for one id? Just do that and stick in in `summarize()`. If you still have trouble, ask a new question.